# Twitter API - Display all tweets with a certain hashtag?

Tags: twitter

How would I go about displaying tweets that contain a certain hashtag using the Twitter API? Thanks

I'd also like to know if there is a way to get all tweets from a certain hashtag in a separate file, also the ones that don't show up in your feed anymore. I suppose that's what the earlier question was about, too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This answer was written in 2010. The API it uses has since been retired. It is kept for historical interest only.

---

[Search](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) for it.

Make sure `include_entities` is set to true to get hashtag results. See [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)

> Returns 5 mixed results with Twitter.com user IDs plus entities for the term "blue angels":
>
> `GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=mixed`

Answer (score 40):

`UPDATE for v1.1:`

Rather than giving `q="search_string"` give it `q="hashtag"` in URL encoded form to return results with HASHTAG ONLY. So your query would become:

```
    GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames
```

`%23` is URL encoded form of `#`. Try the link out in your browser and it should work.

You can optimize the query by adding `since_id` and `max_id` parameters detailed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). Hope this helps !

Note: Search API is now a OAUTH authenticated call, so please include your access_tokens to the above call

**Updated**

Twitter Search doc link:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Comment: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active"

Comment: @Wasim: Edited the answer, the API changed to v1.1, try the above instructions and it should work. Dont forget to add your access_token to the call.

Answer (score 8):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296183/twitter-hash-tag-search-query) worked better for me as it isolates the search on the hashtag, not just returning results that contain the search string. In the answer above you would still need to parse the JSON response to see if the entities.hashtags array is not empty.