# Twitter: Hash tag search query

Tags: search, twitter, hash, hashtag

I am trying to search twitter tweets by a given hashtag. I am trying to get the correct http query, but I have no idea which one. I've tried a few but i can't find the correct one.

I should use the http://api.twitter.com/1/... link.

I already have a search http query by a given name which works correctly

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=prayforjapan
```

Now I would like to search by a given hashtag (for example #prayforjapan)

I tried using a few, but can't find the correct one as I said before. Here's one I tried:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?include_entities=true&hashtag=prayforjapan"
```

Does anyone know which one I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active!!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can simply fetch `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test` to get a list of tweets containing `#test` in JSON, where `%23test` is `#test` URL encoded.

Comment: Yeah, I found that search too, but that one always gives an error in my code, that's why I think I should use the api.twitter. Could it be that it returns a different structure of JSON?

Comment: It returns valid JSON, so if your code fails it might be buggy in some way?

Comment: Yeah, it returns JSON, but in a different order than the other :)

Comment: Just want to add that to get data of next page add &page=2 where 2 is page no.
example :
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test&page=2

Answer (score 5):

Just for people who come this post now. This current format works

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23test&include_entities=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test format shown above, but in recent weeks this format has stopped working.  It returns valid JSON, yes, but the return has zero tweets while a manual search of the hashtag on twitter.com shows one or more results.  This happens with every hashtag I try.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Edit: I've also noticed that adding a hyperlink to a tweet causes it to show up only in my feed, while it fails to show in either site search or JSON.  I'm a Twitter novice; am I missing something basic here?

Comment: add '&include_entities=true' in your search_url

Comment: '&include_entities=true' doesn't fix the issue.  I'm also getting all tweets that contains links excluded from the search results.