# Twitter Search Query in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to pull tweets matching the given search query. I'm using the following code :

```
import urllib2 as urllib
import json
response = urllib.urlopen("https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=microsoft")
pyresponse = json.load(response)
print pyresponse
```

This was working a few days ago, but suddenly stopped working now. With some help from google, I learned that this type of url in not supported anymore.

How do I perform this search query. What url shall I use?

Comment: What do you mean by stopped working? There's no exception.

Comment: I meant this script returned 15 tweets anytime I used it (believe me, I have tried with different keywords and have done some analysis on the tweets), but for past few days the script doesn't return any tweets.

Comment: Also see second answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296183/twitter-hash-tag-search-query?rq=1

Comment: This thread could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data

Answer (score 4):

Twitter is deprecating non-authenticated searches. You should look into Tweepy or another Python library that interacts with Twitter. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy