# Filtering Tweets by hash tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter

I need to filter out and display tweets containing a certain hashtag to a feed on my site

so

1. display all tweets I publish
2. display reply tweets containng certain hash tags

I have been searching the net and cant find anything

were using blogger.js but dont care if I need to change methods (php would be fine)

has anyone seen this or know a mthod I can use?

Comment: I think you don't need much more than regex...

Comment: What are you using to fetch these tweets? Is it important that the server (ie: PHP) processes them or can they just be directly fed to the user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this.

`/i` is for case insensitive matching (since case can make a difference).

```
<?php
$tweets = array("this is a #tiger tweet", "this is a #blood tweet", this is a #horror tweet");
$pattern = array("/#tiger/i", "/#blood/i", "/#horror/i");
for($i = 0; $i < count($pattern); $i++){
   for($j = 0; $j < count($tweets); $j++){
      preg_match($pattern[i], $tweets[j], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
      print_r($matches); //check matches array and decide if you want to show tweet.
   }
}
?>
```

or if you don't want to use regex.

```
<?php
$tweets = array("this is a #tiger tweet", "this is a #blood tweet", this is a #horror tweet");
$pattern = array("#tiger", "#blood", "#horror");
for($i = 0; $i < count($pattern); $i++){
   for($j = 0; $j < count($tweets); $j++){
      $tweet = strtolower(tweets[j]); //lowercase both because we we want to match the tag no matter what the case.
      $pattern = strtolower(patterns[i]);
      if(strpos(tweets[j], pattern[i]) > -1){
      //show
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Comment: `strpos()` supports mixed needles, so there's no need to iterate over them. Also, I'd use `strpos() !== FALSE` for clarity, but that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. @jeff I have not updated the code as I'm assuming you can make the changes NullUserException is talking about.