# C# .net app to pull twitter posts?

Tags: c#, twitter

Can a .net app be made to pull twitter posts?

I am wondering if its possible to capture any of the posts made on twitter by any user? I am trying to obtain an unrestricted flow of tweets to use as sample data for statistical analysis.

I want to try to gauge the sentiment of topics such as "thanksgiving" or "global warming"

I was thinking on a high level I would be able to pull all tweets containing a "#thanksgiving" tag and save them to a SQL DB for analysis.

Is this a valid approach of that, or is there a better way? Is there a tool to do this already that will save me the development time?

Comment: Have you tried googling for 'twitter API'?

Comment: Are you looking to pull the posts of any specific user as in "I'm looking to pull the tweets from Adam" or a global stream from all users?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com).

Specifically, this question contains the answer you'll need to get all tweets with a certain hashtag:

[Twitter API - Display all tweets with a certain hashtag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag)

In terms of tools to do it with, [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) is a C# wrapper for the Twitter API. I can't vouch for it though as I've never used it.