# Twitter XML feed

Tags: php, xml, twitter

I have just coded twitter feed for my statuses fetching the xml. I was wondering if there is any link also for XML of mentions and hashtags

Comment: Regarding Hashtags this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag

Comment: Thank you but I rather use it with cURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For twitter mentions:

```
function curlRequest($url, $post) {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  // we are not using the $post variable yet, but stay tuned!
  if ($post) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  }
return curl_exec($curl);
}

//then call this function as:
$contents= curlRequest(“http://twitter.com/statuses/mentions.xml”, FALSE);
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement($contents);

foreach($xml->status as $status) {
    echo "<li>$status->text</li>";
}
```