# Twitter Phirehose hashtag search not working

Tags: php, api, twitter, hashtag, phirehose

I'm trying to search hashtags on twitter using the Phirehose.
I'm using this code:

```
$sc = new FilterTrackConsumer(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
    $sc->setTrack(array('selfie'));
    $sc->consume();
```

I'm not getting any results using this code.
What am I doing wrong here?
I want to search all of twitter for specified hashtags.

Hope you can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct. See [Twitter API - Display all tweets with a certain hashtag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag)  where it says that "selfie" should match '#selfie", "@selfie", "Selfie", even "`http://selfie.com/`"

You look like you are using the filter-track.php from the example directory? Have you filled in all four defines, and made sure they are correct? Make sure you are seeing any error messages (e.g. they may be going to somewhere under /var/log, or syslog, or something like that).