# Python: How to search tweets and store in database?

Tags: python, twitter

I've got a nice Python script that currently prints out the past 200 tweets from a given username.

However, I'd like to modify it so that instead it will collect the past 200 tweets that include a certain hashtag (from any username) and then I'd like to store those results in a database.

Can anyone provide a suggestion on how to modify the code below?

```
import sys
import operator
import requests
import json
import twitter

twitter_consumer_key = 'XXXX'
twitter_consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
twitter_access_token = 'XXXX'
twitter_access_secret = 'XXXX'

twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=twitter_consumer_key, consumer_secret=twitter_consumer_secret, access_token_key=twitter_access_token, access_token_secret=twitter_access_secret)

statuses = twitter_api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=handle, count=200, include_rts=False)

for status in statuses:
  if (status.lang == 'en'):
    print status
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter API - Display all tweets with a certain hashtag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag)

Comment: [It does not appear to be possible](https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-user-timeline-tag-filtering/17508) to search by hashtag with the [GetUserTimeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) function. As per Xander's suggestion, perhaps the [GetSearch](https://pythonism.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/using-the-twitter-api-with-python-twitter/) method would be helpful. Otherwise, you could download batches of 200 tweets at a time, and filter them yourself (and I think that Twitter limits you to downloading the user's last 3200 tweets or so).

Comment: As for storing in a DB, unless you're working within some framework that provides a DB abstraction layer (i.e. Django, web2py, etc.), check out http://www.sqlalchemy.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the twitter package but this could be a suggestion that you can work on. Depends on how you want to save the tweet, you can replace the "print status" with the way you want. **However, this only allows you to filter the 200 tweets rather than get the 200 tweets that contain certain hashtag.**

```
import sys
import operator
import requests
import json
import twitter

twitter_consumer_key = 'XXXX'
twitter_consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
twitter_access_token = 'XXXX'
twitter_access_secret = 'XXXX'

twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=twitter_consumer_key, consumer_secret=twitter_consumer_secret, access_token_key=twitter_access_token, access_token_secret=twitter_access_secret)

statuses = twitter_api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=handle, count=200, include_rts=False)

tag_list = ["Xmas", "Summer"]
for status in statuses:
  if (status.lang == 'en'):
    #assume there exists a hashtag in the tweet
    for hashtag in status.entities.hashtags:
      if hashtag.text in tag_list:
        print status
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I really need to scan for hashtags from all users (rather than filter a single user's tweets). I can't find any documentation on this "twitter" library I've been using thus far, so I might switch over to something else that has a more useful method.

Comment: @MattBrown Ah, you just want a simple search function. Just noticed on the Twitter official site: "The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days." If you want to match for completeness you can consider using a Streaming API instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a java code that will print out past 100 tweets including '#engineeringproblems' hashtag (from any user). You need to add twitter API 'twitter4J' in the library.

API download link- http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download

Java source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
     .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx")
     .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx")
     .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxx")
     .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxx");

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    Query query = new Query("#engineeringproblems ");
    int numberOfTweets = 100;
    long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    ArrayList<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();

    while (tweets.size() < numberOfTweets) {
        if (numberOfTweets - tweets.size() > 100) {
            query.setCount(100);
        } else {
            query.setCount(numberOfTweets - tweets.size());
        }
        try {
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
            System.out.println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets" + "\n");
            for (Status t : tweets) {
                if (t.getId() < lastID) {
                    lastID = t.getId();
                }
            }

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
        };
        query.setMaxId(lastID - 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
        Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);


        String user = t.getUser().getScreenName();
        String msg = t.getText();

        System.out.println(i + " USER: " + user + " wrote: " + msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I've really been looking for a Python solution and I believe I've finally found it and tested it successfully. Code is below. Still looking for a way to modify the script to enter each line into a SQL database, but I hopefully I can find that elsewhere.

pip install TwitterSearch

```
from TwitterSearch import *
try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder() # create a TwitterSearchOrder object
    tso.set_keywords(['Guttenberg', 'Doktorarbeit']) # let's define all words we would like to have a look for
    tso.set_language('de') # we want to see German tweets only
    tso.set_include_entities(False) # and don't give us all those entity information

    # it's about time to create a TwitterSearch object with our secret tokens
    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = 'aaabbb',
        consumer_secret = 'cccddd',
        access_token = '111222',
        access_token_secret = '333444'
     )

     # this is where the fun actually starts :)
    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) )

except TwitterSearchException as e: # take care of all those ugly errors if there are some
    print(e)
```